# Doxygen is not generating calls for functions out of scope

Tags: doxygen

Is it possible to Doxygen to generate calls to a functions that are out of INPUT scope? (For C language)

I mean, lets assume following code:

```
#include <someHeader.h>

void func(void)
{
    functionFromHeader();
}
```

I would like to have `functionFromHeader` listed in `references` field within the generated field, even if the `someHeader.h` is not listed in `INPUT` field in config file.

Is there any config that could generate such calls?

**EDIT:**

Version of doxygen: 1.8.15

Configuration elements changed due default config:

```
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = YES
WARN_LOGFILE           = warn.log
RECURSIVE              = YES
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
GENERATE_XML           = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = somePath
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = NO
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = YES
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = NO
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
DOT_PATH               = .\graphviz\bin\
DOTFILE_DIRS           = .\dots
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 10000
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 1
DOT_CLEANUP            = NO
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. What would be the difference between using `functionFromHeader` and e.g. `sin` or other library function? Can you complete your code with at least the differences you made to the default doxygen configuration file and the configuration file you used?

Comment: @albert I have edited the original post to provide answer to your questions

Comment: Answering the question about difference between `functionFromHeader` and `sin` I see no difference. For both, the header/source file is not in the INPUT

Comment: Indeed and e.g. `sin`  is also not shown in the `references` field, so why should `functionFromHeader` be shown / how can / should doxygen distinguish between `sin` and `functionFromHeader`?

Comment: So maybe we do not understand each other. My question is: Is it possible to show `sin` usage in `references`?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no possibility other than to make the function known to doxygen, in this case, by means of the  include file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217446/discussion-between-tomasz-and-albert).

Comment: For me there is nothing to continue.